# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module after compile with babel

Tags: javascript, laravel, babeljs, laravel-mix

Currently I am writing a chat application in laravel 5.8. When I run yarn run prod with babel I get an Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

in my webpack.mix.js I have this line of code:

```js
 mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').babel('public/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js');
```

The problem in my code is an async map callback function which I need because I perform an ajax call in it.

```js
Promise.all(Object.values(this.contacts).map(async (contact) => {
    await contact.links.user.resolve().then((User) => {
        this.users.push(User);
    });
    return this.users;
})).then(function(Users){ ... });
```

If I run yarn run prod without the babel it all works fine.

```js
 mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

I have already tried to update my babel, to use different babel plugins, use forEach instead of map

Comment: Are you positive that code is what's causing this? Because the error message mentions an `import` statement. Also, I'm pretty sure that code can be shortened to `Promise.all(Object.values(this.contacts).map(contact => contact.links.user.resolve()))
  .then(users => { this.users = users; /* ... */ });`

Comment: The Error does not appear if i remove the async statement. I think babel imports something wrong to polyfill this function. Also i checked the the compiled app.js and the first statement is  `import _regeneratorRuntime from"@babel/runtime/regenerator";` which causes the error